# Python closes immediately before executing

Tags: python-3.x, windows

when I execute my code, it causes the execution window to open up and close instantly. Note that this is prior to execution of my programme, as the several inputk=input("blablabla") I have in my code don't show up before the window closes.

I ask for advice on what is happening.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: this is most likely a windows/environment issue, not a code issue (python doesn't have "execution windows").  if you can provide details, i'd suggest posting in [Super User](https://superuser.com/) not StackOverflow

Comment: @jdigital This could easily be an issue with code, such as a script with a syntax error that is executed via double click. OP, please provide your code so we can have some actual information

Comment: py.exe (python.exe) is a console application, which means it either allocates a new console or attaches to an inherited console at startup. If it allocates a new console, then by default there's no other process attached to the console after Python exits, and the window gets destroyed. Either run your script with an inherited console (e.g. from a CMD shell); or add `-i` to the script's shebang (e.g. `#!python3 -i`) to start the Python shell (REPL) after the script exits; or call the main function from a try-finally in which the `finally` statement runs `subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')`.